# How can the number of strongly connected components of a graph change if a new edge is added

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory

Exercise: 22.5-1 CLRS
How can the number of strongly connected components of a graph change if a new
edge is added?

[Somewhere](http://student.csuci.edu/~douglas.holmes253/Assignment6.html) the answer given is If a new edge is added, one of two things could happen.

1) If the new edge connects two vertices that belong to a strongly connected component, the number of strongly connected components will remain the same.

2) If, instead, the edge connects two strongly connected components, and the edge is in the reverse direction of an existing path between the two components, then a new strongly connected component will be made, increasing the number of components. 

**I think the second point is incorrect.**
Lets say we have two strongly connected component **C**  and **C'** 

a) If no edge or edge **C->C'** exists between them and new edge connects as **C->C'**  then nothing will happen.

b) If edge  **C->C'**  exists between them and new edge connects as **C'->C**  then C' will be merged to C decreasing the number of strongly connected component by 1 as every vertex will be reachable from each other.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: I agree with the quoted answer. Suppose you have two SCC ie C and C'. Now, in the undirected graph, a new edge is added-D. There is only edge going from C to D. In this case, there is no possibility of reaching any other vertex from D. Hence, D becomes an independent SCC. Now, the total SSC for this graph is 3 ie C,C', D. Please correct me if I'm wrong:)

Comment: @GAURIMNIT I think SCC is meant for directed graph only. And if its undirected graph it means all the edges will be bidirectional and therefore if you are able to reach from C to D then its implicit that you can reach from D to C as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're exactly correct. The answer you quoted is wrong in its description: adding edges is only ever going to decrease the number of strongly connected components. Once all possible edges have been added, there's just a single strongly connected component left - the entire graph.