# Strongly Connected Components - Adding edges

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory

related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545463/how-can-the-number-of-strongly-connected-components-of-a-graph-change-if-a-new-e)

According to the illustration(below) of partitioning the SCCs of the graph [explained in this site](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/) there are 3 SCCs circled in red and WHAT I UNDERSTAND from this is sometimes adding edges to a strongly connected graph will increase the number of SCCs.  (We can simply add another out edge 4->5 and number of SCCs will increase by 1)
[image] 
The explanation above and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545463/how-can-the-number-of-strongly-connected-components-of-a-graph-change-if-a-new-e) seem contradictory. Please help me to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that you only add edges between nodes that already exist in the graph, the the number of SCCs cannot increase. Specifically, the edge either runs from a node in one SCC to a node in a descendant SCC (no new SCCs added) or from a node in one SCC to a node in an ancestor SCC, which will reduce the number of SCCs.

Your example of adding more SCC's assumes that the newly-added edge connects an existing node (4) to a nonexistent node (5) that would also have to be added. If you're allowed to add new nodes to the graph, then yes, you can increase the number of SCCs as you've shown above. However, if you're forced to have edges running between existing nodes, then the number of SCCs can only go down.

Hope this helps!